# Currently on Rails 3, starting to write unit tests, so is it better to go with Rspec or Minitest given the future of Rails 6 and unit testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, minitest

I need advice. Our software is currently on Rails 3 and we're starting to write unit tests, but we can't decide whether to go with RSpec or Minitest. we're considering to go with RSpec purely over the fact that some of us have experience in it (slight bias included) and that we like the look of it better, syntactically.

But as we're considering future-proofing out software for when we upgrade the Rails versions. As Minitest comes as a default with Rails 5, it seems like the community is turning to Minitest over Rspec for that reason (but not 100% certain if that's the case). With Rails 6 coming in April, it seems all the more reason with go with MiniTest is because new ability to parallel test.

Do you think it's better to go with MiniTest over RSpec, or do you think Rspec will be able to compete with MiniTest still?

Comment: This is exactly what SO should be for, but unfortunately the question will probably be deleted.

We use Rspec with a parallel-testing gem to get the best of both worlds, but as you say it looks like the community as a whole is moving towards Minitest

Comment: Didn't think to look for a gem for parallel testing for RSpec. But we shall take that into consideration as well. Agreed that the community is moving to Minitest, but I bet RSpec will try to stay alive as long as possible, as it is well-loved by the community. 

Can't also have homework questions on SO :) Gotta mix it up a bit here.

Comment: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests - It's pretty tasty :)

Comment: Proposed it to the team, and they loved the idea :) Thanks Mark! We really like RSpec so we really want to stick with it.

Comment: Glad you found it useful! :)